# Finding unity and units of a binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Let $\ast$ be the binary operation defined on $\mathbb{N}$ by $m \ast n = \max (m, n)$; the largest of $m$ and $n$. Decide whether unity exists and if so, find the units.

I know that unity is defined as $m * e=e * m=m$ so then $\max(m,e)=m$ which would be possible for all $m>e$ right? Does that mean that is the unity? Or is that the units? Thank you!

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$? On what set is the binary operation defined?

Comment: sorry, missed that part! @sqtrat

Comment: Sure $m\ast n= n\ast m=m$ for all $n \leq m$, but in order for it to be a unit, it has to hold for all such $m$, so what do you think?

Comment: OH! so does that mean there is no unity then since there's no one $m$ where that is always true?

Comment: No, see answer by egreg.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose $e$ exists; then $0*e=0$, so you have not many choices for $e$, do you? Next show that the candidate is indeed the neutral element.

Comment: so e is 0 then?

Comment: @Alex It has to be $0$, if it exists. Now prove that $0$ indeed has the required property.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to prove it. Is the fact that 0 is the smallest number in the natural numbers enough? Also, since $e=0$ does that mean the units are $m\gt 0$? Thank you!

Comment: @Alex Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$; then $\max(m,0)=m$. There is *no* invertible element except $0$: if $\max(m,n)=0$, then $m=n=0$.

Comment: so that followed by something like "so $0*m=m*0=m$ so $e=0$" is an adequate proof?

Comment: @Alex “so $0$ is the neutral element” (or whatever term you use).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $(X,\leq)$ be any linearly ordered set with minimum element $0$. Defining $x\ast y = max\{x,y\}$ will always yield a unique unit. Which one?